# Helm doesn't install StorageClass

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I define [storage class](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/) in `templates` with name `ssd` and when I install the package, `kubectl get storageclass` doesn't list it and it cannot be used in `PersistentVolumeClaims`. It sounds like a helm bug or is there anything else I have to do for this `StorageClass` object to be loaded by k8s ? Because `kubectl create -f storage-class.yaml` actually loads it correctly, but helm does not.

Comment: Please post your helm chart

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug in helm, it works after helm upgrade to the latest version.